# How to ZIP all documents that expired (TTL) and upload it to cold storage(S3) using change stream in AWS DocumentDB

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-documentdb

In our application we are having a collection in MongoDB(AWS DocumentDB) where we store data with TTL is set on the document to expire after certain duration(30 days). We want to collect all the data that are expired on daily basis, zip them and archive it to AWS S3 for audit & data retention as per guidelines.

Would appreciate pointers on how we can achieve it using the change stream or any other method to achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions to achieve this:

- [Change streams](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/archive-data-from-amazon-documentdb-with-mongodb-compatibility-to-amazon-s3/) to sync data to S3, delete expired using a TTL index
- [Rolling collection](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/optimize-data-archival-costs-in-amazon-documentdb-using-rolling-collections/) strategy

For your case, daily archiving, I would look at the rolling collection option, it's simpler and more cost effective.
I linked the blogs that describe these two solutions in more detail.